# Which package is needed to achieve this LaTeX output?

Tags: fonts, packages, document-classes

I've recently read a maths paper (outside of my area of study, economics) and it seems to use a font and/or style which I am unfamiliar with. I do not have access to the .tex or .cls file for this paper so I cannot ascertain what document class and packages are used to achieve this output. Can anyone enlighten me on this?

The paper is here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610903v1.pdf

Comment: use the documentclass `amsart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following from the comment, the way to achieve this style is to use the `amsart` document class.